# To copy data from 232 excel worksheets present in a single excel workbook into a destination worksheet.The row name and worksheet name should be same

Tags: vba, excel

To copy data from 232 excel worksheets present in a single excel workbook into a destination excel worksheet present in the same workbook with the criteria that row name in the destination worksheet should be same as worksheetname.Since while naming a worksheet in an excel file we have restriction in size,so for some worksheet the names are written short but in the destiantion worksheet the names are written in fullform.So for some worksheets the data is not accumulated.How to fix this issue?Please help.I am new to VBA

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sheetName As String
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""

        sheetName = Cells(i, 1)
        Cells(i, 4) = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(190, 7).Value
        Cells(i, 5) = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(191, 7).Value
        Cells(i, 6) = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(192, 7).Value
        Cells(i, 7) = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(193, 7).Value
        Cells(i, 8) = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(194, 7).Value
        Cells(i, 9) = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(195, 7).Value
        Cells(i, 10) = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(196, 7).Value
        i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code (since max length for sheet name when renaming a worksheet manually is 31 character you can restrict `sheetName`):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sheetName As String
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""

        sheetName = IIf(Len(Cells(i, 1))>31,Left(Cells(i, 1),31),Cells(i, 1))
        Cells(i, 4) = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(190, 7).Value
        Cells(i, 5) = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(191, 7).Value
        Cells(i, 6) = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(192, 7).Value
        Cells(i, 7) = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(193, 7).Value
        Cells(i, 8) = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(194, 7).Value
        Cells(i, 9) = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(195, 7).Value
        Cells(i, 10) = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(196, 7).Value
        i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I got subscript out of range in line Cells(i, 4) = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(190, 7).Value

Comment: How did you generate your short names from fullnames?

Comment: I just wrote the name till the criteria of 31 characters met.For eg.My tab names are Afghanistan,Bhutan,Bermuda,Albania,Algeria.For Afghanistan,Albania,Algeria the data got accumulated but for Bhutan it showed subscript out of range error

Comment: @simoco: This question is a followup from [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145352/copy-data-from-different-worksheet) The problem with `sheetName = IIf(Len(Cells(i, 1))>31,Left(Cells(i, 1),31),Cells(i, 1))` is that this can give you false positives. For example what if first 31 characters of multiple sheets are the same?

Comment: @user3045652: Is there a reason why you are ignoring my advice as in previous thread on how to find the error if the sheet names do not match? :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, you are correct, but I assumed that user3045652 just took the first 31 characters (and from his comment above it's true)

Comment: yeah we both posted at the same time :P

Comment: @user3045652, this code gives you error for sheetname `Bhutan` ? do you have sheet with this name?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Sorry,actually while writing the question I forgot to mention the second part of the problem so I wrote the question twice.There are 232 tabs so I am just renaming my sheet names as per my cell name.I tried for 4 tabs.For 3 it worked but for the fourth one it again showed a subscript out of range error.

Comment: @user3045652: Do you actually have a "Bhutan" Sheet? If yes, then are you sure that the cell have only "Bhutan"?

Comment: @simoco Yeah I do have a sheet named as Bhutan

Comment: check please maybe you have some spaces in cell or in sheet name? for example `"Bhutan "` (not just `"Bhutan"`)

Comment: If CheckSheet(sheetName) Then
            Cells(i, 4) = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(190, 7).Value
            Cells(i, 5) = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(191, 7).Value
            
        End IfFunction CheckSheet(ByVal sSheetName As String) As Boolean
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim bReturn As Boolean

    For Each oSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

        If oSheet.Name = sSheetName Then

            bReturn = True
            Exit For

        End If

    Next oSheet

    CheckSheet = bReturn

End Function


@simoco@siddharth By modfying code like this it worked.

Comment: try to post it like edit to your question, since in comments it's looks unreadable